# Laravel Exception Handler prevents Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation, exception

I have Validator rules setup for form inputs, and I wish to also handle exceptions caused by users directly entering in slugs (www.{myApp}.com/admin/users/2/edit) if not authorized.

When I add the 'render' method in app/Exceptions/Handler.php, it overrides my app/Http/Requests invocation of my custom rules when a user enters in invalid data for a particular form field (that would normally be handled by the Validator via my controller action's type-hinted Request parameter).

Can someone point me to a good resource where I can learn more, or provide a code snippet that might address this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you not catching ValidationException instead of changing the render method?

Comment: I was looking to change the render method to catch exceptions caused by users entering invalid slugs (i.e. www.{myApp}.com/admin/1/edit), but it also catches form validation errors that are currently handled via 'Validator'.  I'm not set on changing the render method, I'm open to any suggestions that would help, as my testing of ValidationException didn't seem to fare well.